# Correct Screw length I should be buying

Tags: screws, carpentry

Can you help me out. I am planning to install this (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rubbermaid-70-in-White-Twin-Track-Upright-for-Wood-or-Wire-Shelving-FG4B8900WHT/100047070) in my cabinet to add organizer inside my closet. I am not sure though what should be the lenght of the wood screw that I will be using if I will install it in the stud. Note that depth of that material is around 1 inches. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add up all the parts:

- Bracket - your questions says "about 1 inches" but I usually find these types of brackets (but haven't used exactly this one) are a bit thinner than 1 inch
- Cabinet back - varies, might not be any at all
- Drywall or other wall material - typically 1/2"
- Between 1 inch and 2 inches into the stud. Studs are nominally 3-1/2" thick, but if there is any possibility of wires going through the studs then you don't want to go more than 1-1/2" in.

So that makes a total of 2-1/2" to 3" typical.

As noted elsewhere, don't use drywall screws. They are handy, but they are not designed to hold a heavy load, which is important for shelving brackets.

Comment: I was planning to use wood screw is that good one? Can I use deck crew? I am going to home depot tomorrow to buy screw

Comment: IMHO, wood screws or deck screws would both be fine.

Comment: Just a question do you think there would be negative effect of using deck screw instead of wood screw? Cant find answer on google if there is a negative effect of using deck screw. I got could of deck screw that fits the length not sure if it will bite me after couple of years

Comment: I think deck screws would be fine.

Comment: I'd go with deck screws or chipboard screws, traditional wood scrws are too much hassle and not as strong.